# Need to inject data in first two columns using mysql query

Tags: mysql, csv

Hi below is my mysql query

```
select CONCAT(si.ID_PREFIX, si.ID_COUNT) as ID, tmp.NEW_VALUE from ( select ACTIVITY_ID, ISSUE_ID, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE from SCARAB_ACTIVITY where ISSUE_ID in (select ISSUE_ID from SCARAB_ISSUE where MODULE_ID = 656)  and (NEW_VALUE like 'http%') order by ACTIVITY_ID desc) tmp, SCARAB_ISSUE si where tmp.ISSUE_ID = si.ISSUE_ID INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/nxh5102_relatedlinks.csv' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '' TERMINATED BY ',';
```

The above would collect the data and store it into a csv file something,ike below :

```
SEE25,https://www.hello.com/sf/tracker/do/viewArtifact/projects.ip_forge/tracker.open_issues/artf31417?_message=1344426489584&returnUrlKey=
SEE355,https://www.google.com/svn/nxh5102/trunk/doc/010 Architecture and Design/MRA3/PRCR doc/NxHSEE355.pptx
```

I need to add one more row in the first line something like below:

```
Artifact ID,Related Links
SEE25,https://www.hello.com/sf/tracker/do/viewArtifact/projects.ip_forge/tracker.open_issues/artf31417?_message=1344426489584&returnUrlKey=
SEE355,https://www.google.com/svn/nxh5102/trunk/doc/010 Architecture and Design/MRA3/PRCR doc/NxHSEE355.pptx
```

I want this so that when i open the csv in excel i could see them in first two columns. Any sugeesstion would be helpful.

Comment: You really don't like the word JOIN do you?

Comment: @Strawberry i didnt get your point!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 'artifact' id
     , 'related links' new_value
 UNION 
SELECT CONCAT(si.id_prefix, si.id_count)
     , si.new_value 
  FROM scarab_activity sa
  JOIN scarab_issue si
    ON si.issue_id = sa.issue_id    
 WHERE si.module_id = 656
   AND sa.new_value LIKE 'http%'
```